# Stop Steam opening window when computer starts

Tags: steam, pc

Is there a way to enable the "Run Steam when my computer starts" option without any window to appear when I login?

This way Steam will start running as an icon in the system tray in the bottom right, ensuring that everything is up-to-date, but it won't bother me if I don't want to use it/play a game immediately.

Comment: ...isn't the default for Steam to start in the system tray without bugging you?  I know that's what mine does.

Comment: @Powerlord mine too.  I'll poke through the settings to see if I can find a built-in setting for that, since launch options at runtime is the best Arqade has come up with so far.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use **Steam launch options**, which can be used to change game settings and enable features.

For example one of these launch options is:

***-silent*** : Launches Steam to the system tray only. Normal Steam windows will only appear after clicking the system tray icon. If a password is not stored, the normal login window will still be displayed.

More info about *Launch options* [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5623-QOSV-5250).

Comment: This option never even occurred to me, having Steam launch silently on start up. Very handy!

Comment: The instructions at the provided link say to create a new shortcut with the `-silent` option. When the "Run Steam when my computer starts" checkbox is checked, doesn't it directly execute steam.exe? What would cause it to execute the newly created shortcut instead?

Comment: @Vince if you kill the previous process and start it again with the newly created shortcut, the launch option is probably saved for future executions. This is the suggested way, I really don't know.

Answer (score 2):

UNCHECK "Run Steam when my computer starts" in the settings and put a shortcut of steam with -nochatui -nofriendsui -silent in run => shell:startup